# changes in query optimizer from mysql 5.5.59 to 5.7.21

Tags: mysql

We have upgraded our database hardware, and also to ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04. This comes with an update to mysql. We are having some pretty hefty performance issues. I think one of the issues has something to do with the config of mysql and how it is handling the optimization of queries.

I can't quite put my finger on why a query with products_id and language_id as the primary key wouldn't be used by default. Both fields are integers.

Is there a setting that we're missing in the config of mysql that would be setting this behavior?

```
products_description | CREATE TABLE `products_description` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `products_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `products_description` text,
  `products_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_viewed` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `products_name_sphinx` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `idx_products_name_zen` (`products_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=454992 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is a query running in zen cart that on 5.5.59 is at least using indexes:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `p`.`products_id` AS `id`, `pd`.`products_name` AS 
`name` FROM `products` AS `p` LEFT JOIN `products_description` AS `pd` ON 
`p`.`products_id`=`pd`.`products_id` WHERE `p`.`products_status`="1" AND `pd`.`language_id`="1"\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_products_status_zen
          key: idx_products_status_zen
      key_len: 1
          ref: const
         rows: 108053
        Extra:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pd
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: p.products_id,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On the new 5.7.21

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `p`.`products_id` AS `id`, `pd`.`products_name` AS `name` FROM `products` AS `p` LEFT JOIN `products_description` AS `pd` ON `p`.`products_id`=`pd`.`products_id` WHERE `p`.`products_status`="1" AND `pd`.`language_id`="1"\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pd
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 192860
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_products_status_zen
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: pd.products_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 55.95
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

If I put force index into the query:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `p`.`products_id` AS `id`, `pd`.`products_name` AS `name` FROM `products` AS `p`, products_description `pd` force index (PRIMARY) WHERE p.products_id=pd.products_id and `p`.`products_status`=1 AND `pd`.`language_id`=1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_products_status_zen
          key: idx_products_status_zen
      key_len: 1
          ref: const
         rows: 108024
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pd
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: p.products_id,const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

EDIT: Here's the format=json explain:
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "86465.63"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "pd",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 192860,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 19286,
          "filtered": "10.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "59465.23",
            "eval_cost": "3857.20",
            "prefix_cost": "63322.43",
            "data_read_per_join": "8M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "products_id",
            "language_id",
            "products_name"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`pd`.`language_id` = 1)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "p",
          "access_type": "eq_ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "PRIMARY",
            "idx_products_status_zen"
          ],
          "key": "PRIMARY",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "products_id"
          ],
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "toolsource_zc.pd.products_id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 10791,
          "filtered": "55.95",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "19286.00",
            "eval_cost": "2158.22",
            "prefix_cost": "86465.63",
            "data_read_per_join": "4M"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "products_id",
            "products_status"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`p`.`products_status` = 1)"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If most of your products have "products_status=1" (I assume it means "enabled"?), reversing the join order (you are aware it is not  a left join!?) can be a valid execution path depending on the data in your second table - which MySQL can only guess about (as there is no index on language_id only), and if it is slower, it may guessed incorrectly. Use `explain format=json` to see its expectations. Also: is this actually the query that is slower, or just a query that you saw using different execution path? Usually, I would expect a "limit" and/or "order by" instead of reading 100k products.

Comment: This is just one that jumped out, but I'm seeing many queries that have that table that aren't using an index. There are approximately 50% more products in the table that aren't enabled (products_status=0). The original query was written by someone else and I'll change it. But my issue is with that we just changed servers, not the queries themselves. That's the issue I'm trying to understand and resolve.

Comment: Not using a non-covering index can be a valid choice compared to doing a full table scan if you need a large part of your table anyway. Be aware that MySQL 5.7 chose to execute the query in a different order (first read the descriptions, then the products) compared to MySQL 5.5 (start with products, then look up the description), so you cannot really compare the plans (or indexes). Both are valid strategies. To get a better idea why MySQL 5.7 chose that way, you/we need query costs for both 5.7 queries from `explain format=json`. And again: is that query actually slower (and by how much)?

Comment: On a sidenote: You are pretending to outer join, but then you limit this to `pd.language_id = 1` thus dismissing all outer-joined rows. Either use an inner join or put the condition in the ON clause. Then why `= "1"`? Double quotes are for names in SQL and this is even a number, hence `= 1`.

Comment: As to indexes: they usually make sense when accessing very few of the records in the table. This seems not to be the case in your query, however.

Comment: Thorsten: I totally understand. Even rewriting the query without the " around the integers, it's the same. My point is that our new server which is much more powerful is running poorly and I'm not sure where to look. This issue is something that seems like a plausible direction.

Comment: Just to make sure you didn't miss it: we need the json-explain for *both* queries on 5.7 to get an idea why MySQL decided that way. Also, is the first query actually slower? I repeat: both ways to execute your query are completely valid! It is not an error, and "all" is fine for that plan. But it's always possible that MySQL (5.5 too) chooses a wrong plan (e.g. because of incomplete information), which is what index hints are for. A more general idea: you are using MyISAM. If someone set up the 5.7 server for you (hosting?), he might have optimized it for innodb (which is the default now).

Comment: Hi Solarflare - thank you for continuing to follow up - very helpful :) I'm having problems getting 5.5 to do json format.  I understand your point about them both being valid however. When I run the query with SQL_NO_CACHE with and without the index hint, it's a noticable difference. With the hint is .8 seconds. Without the hint it is 1.2 seconds. This is pretty beefy hardware that is run in house. This isn't the only query that's like this. Many queries that appear to be 'optimized' before are no longer optimized. All that has changed in the hardware / mysql version.

Comment: 5.5 does not have json output, I meant both 5.7-queries (with and without force index). I guess it will show that MySQL thinks reading 200k rows in details and looking up 20k products is faster than reading 100k products, looking up 100k details and throwing 80k of these away (looking up 100k rows per index is a lot slower than reading a table with 100k rows). The problem is, 20k is wrong (but MySQL doesn't have any details about this). Try adding an index for `language_id`. Even if it isn't used, it might tell MySQL that the distribution is different than it thinks. Or use index hints.

Comment: But I think we got lost in details. I am trying to explain why MySQL 5.7. is doing everything right for this query (and help make this specific query faster), but you want to know why 5.7 is generally slower on faster hardware. How fast is your query on 5.5? I strongly suggest to check your server configuration. MyISAM uses a) the os file cache for data and b) different memory settings than InnoDB. If your 5.5 was optimized for MyISAM, and 5.7 either for InnoDB (the default since 2010) or has default settings, this might explain it. Checking your config would belong on dba.stackexchange.com.